# VBA CDate(Now()) results in Type Mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

It seems I keep finding rare errors in VBA excel.

`CDate(Now())` results in "Compile Error: Expected: Identifier" and "Run-time error: '13': Type Mismatch"

```
Cell(1,1) = Now()
Date1 = Cell(1,1).Value
cell(1,2) = Now()
Date2 = Cell(1,2).Value
If CDate(Date1) > CDate(Date2) Then
     MsgBox "Date1 is older than date2"
End If
```

Now() returns "Thu, 6/24/21 1:20:14 AM "

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me with the Cell >> Cells fix.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables properly. Make sure `Date1` is either declared `As Date` or `As Double` not `As String`. Also make sure your cells are **not** formatted as text but either as number format general or date.

Also note that the [Now function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function) does not return a string `"Thu, 6/24/21 1:20:14 AM"` as you said but a numeric `Variant/Date`. It is just displayed as a string.

Something like the following should work properly:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Cells(1, 1) = Now  ' stores a number like 44371,3385185185 in the cell that is shown in your desired format eg as 2021-06-24 08:07:28 (depends on your number format)
    Dim Date1 As Date
    Date1 = CDate(Cells(1, 1).Value)  ' reads the Double value 44371,3385185185 from the cell and converts it into date
    
    Cells(1, 2) = Now
    Dim Date2 As Date
    Date2 = CDate(Cells(1, 2).Value)
    
    If Date1 > Date2 Then
         MsgBox "Date1 is older than date2"
    End If
End Sub
```

If this throws an error your cells are probably formatted as text.